# Getting GROUP_CONCAT values as individual values

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to implement a simple tagging system (messing around in php)...

I use the following sql command to get the required thread, its author and the tags associated with it:

```
$thread = select_Query("SELECT thread.title, thread.id as t_id,
                         thread.content, author.username, author.id as a_id,
                         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR ',') AS tags
                         FROM thread JOIN thread_tags ON thread.id = thread_tags.thread_id
                         JOIN tags ON thread_tags.tag_id = tags.id
                         INNER JOIN author on author.id = thread.author_id
                         WHERE thread.id = $id", $link);
```

As you can see, I am using GROUP_CONCAT. This works fine, however when I do this, the tags all appear in one variable and I know I can use `$pieces = explode(",", $thread['tags]);`
However is there another way of doing this? I am asking this because tags are easy to separate however if it was something more complex (e.g. something that contain the delimiter ,).

My database schema is as follows:

> thread: id, content, title, author_id
>
> thread_tags: id, tag_id, thread_id
>
> tags: id, name

Comment: Why would a tag contain a , delimiter? I would think that the program itself should count that as a tag separation and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Not tags, something else that also might have a one to many relationship with the thread,.."tags are easy to separate however if it was something more complex (e.g. something that contain the delimiter ,)." The however part says something more complex.

Comment: there is some hints about group_concat in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to squish multiple values into a single cell. This isn't how SQL was designed to be used and as you correctly point out it can cause problems if your separator appears as one of the values.

Luckily there is a way to solve this by rewriting your query. The solution is to return multiple rows instead of multiple values in a cell. Effectively you are *normalizing* your result set.

In other words, instead of this:

```
1 tag_1,tag_2,tag_3
2 tag_2,tag_4,tag_5
```

Do this:

```
1 tag_1
1 tag_2
1 tag_3
2 tag_2
2 tag_4
2 tag_5
```

Doing this naïvely can result in duplicating the same values for the other columns, which can be wasting bandwidth unnecessarily if those columns could potentially contain a lot of data. The solution to this is to use two queries.

In other words instead of this:

```
1 foo bar tag_1
1 foo bar tag_2
1 foo bar tag_3
2 baz qux tag_2
2 baz qux tag_4
2 baz qux tag_5
```

Do this:

```
Result 1:
1 foo bar
2 baz qux

Result 2:
1 tag_1
1 tag_2
1 tag_3
2 tag_2
2 tag_4
2 tag_5
```

Now your result set is in normal form. Also note that you no longer need to run a DISTINCT operation as your results already are distinct. In fact these two queries much more closely match your original database tables so the queries can be much simpler and it will run faster.

Comment: I was just writing an answer that basically said exactly this, so +1 from me!

Comment: He's already doing this, look at his query.  Its group concat, so he doesn't have a result set that duplicates the thread title, content etc for every single row.

Comment: @profitphp: I think you have misunderstood. He has tried to solve the problem of duplicating rows by stuffing multiple values into a single cell. While that "works", it's not the "SQL way" to do it. I think you need to read all my answer quite carefully - it may at first seem that he only needs to apply the first part of the answer, but once he does that he will see that he will also need to apply the second. It would be much easier to see this if you had the query and the results on the screen, but you'll just have to imagine it. I've provided examples to help make it easier to imagine.

Comment: So basically, I should fetch the thread and its associated author,.. then perform another query to fetch all tags associated with that thread? Have I understood you correctly... (I'm a bit slow, lol)

Comment: @profitphp: Did you grasp the point I was trying to make yet? I think my original examples were perhaps a little confusing because my "ids" were letters and my "tags" were numbers. Maybe that's why you couldn't understand my answer before. I've made a slight change to the examples - is it any easier to understand now?

Comment: I understood it fine, you wasted a lot of time explaining what he already did.  You should have just said the 2nd part instead of being redundant.  It could have been summed up as, "don't concatenate, use 2 queries".  As he already had been using a normalized version of the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the delimiter that `GROUP_CONCAT` uses to something that won't appear in the tag, maybe the '|' character.

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tags.name ORDER BY tags.name DESC SEPARATOR '|')
```

You can also validate the tag field and make sure that it does not contain the delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Most tagging systems have a fixed set of requirements for what characters can or cannot be in tags. You could just disallow `,` characters in your tags, and it'd work fine.