# group_concat MYSQL new line

Tags: php, mysql

```
group_concat(A,' ',B,' ',C) as Name,
```

then using this php for displaying

```
<td><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
```

using this query returns Name X,Y

but i prefer to have the names not comma separated rather line break 
X
then Y new line

Any idea?

Comment: group_concat(A,'\\n ',B,'\\n ',C) as Name,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand what do you mean by line break between X and Y, but if you need the values to be comma separated you can add any separator to the [Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like that:

```
group_concat(Name SEPARATOR ' ') as Name
```

and here is [some other separators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping/452419#452419) you can use.

Comment: I wanted to use </br> so that the next name goes to a new line

Comment: The separator is just a string. HTML tags have no special meaning in SQL.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario absolutely, but i didn't no why it returns null when i try it???

Comment: For those looking for how to insert a line break it can be done if you're generating the query pragmatically. For vb.net you would do something like, "SELECT group_concat(field SEPARATOR '" & vblf & "') FROM table"

Comment: Also make sure in your html that your not using <?=htmlspecialchars($obj['name']) ?> you have to use <?php echo $obj['name'];?> This stumped me for a long time trying to get a line break in a GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 32):

For MySQL (or plain text) output You could use `\n` as a separator:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column1 SEPARATOR '\n') FROM table1;
```

I use this very often when I need to get many *new-line-separated* values in one row for other processing.

Comment: `separator '\r\n'` exported the way I wanted for Excel

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out.
this is the correct way to add line break as seperator in the **browser**:

```
group_concat(A,' ',B,' ',C separator '<br>') as Name,
```

Answer (score 1):

[Example](https://rextester.com/SKCUWM68920)

```
SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(city SEPARATOR '\n') AS city, nb
FROM
(SELECT 'A' AS Name, 'Agra' AS city, 101 AS nb
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS Name, 'Delhi' AS city, 102 AS nb
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS Name, 'Allahabad' AS city, 101 AS nb) AS a
GROUP BY Name, nb;
```