# Connecting two tables with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

First of all i am new here & sorry if this question sounds silly, here's my question.

I have two tables like this

1.jobseets

2.jobsheet_tasks

the table jobsheets stores some basic information like customer, date & the jobsheet_tasks only stores the tasks  related to each job sheet.

on "jobsheets_tasks" table. the id of the "jobsheets" that belongs tasks belongs it is storing for reference purpose

here are my tables

[tabels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngWh6.jpg)

there can be one more more tasks under a job sheet.

[Relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cH5fH.jpg)

in order to get the information in both tables i have written the following query.

```
public function get_jobsheets() {
$this->db->select('jobsheets.id, jobsheets.vehicle_number, jobsheets_tasks.task');  
$this->db->from('jobsheets');
$this->db->join('jobsheets_tasks', 'jobsheets_tasks.jobsheet_id = jobsheets.id');

$query = $this->db->get();


if($query->num_rows() > 0) {

  foreach ($query->result()as $row){

   $data[] = $row;

  }
return $data ;
  }


}
```

and i am showing the data in my view like this.

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $jobsheet)  {

  ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->id;?></td>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->vehicle_number;?></td>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->task;?></td>
 <?php } ?>
```

and the output is like this

[wrong output][3]

the query works, but the thing is  as you can see in the above image the tasks named 1 & 2 are belongs to a one job sheetete which job sheet id is 61.

in the view the tasks belongs to same job sheets shown as separate rows, i want to show the data like this.

[correct output][3]

tasks of same job sheet one after another.

please assist me to achieve this. please provide your solutions in code level.

Thanks.

Comment: you can post your output of job details.

Comment: @Nikunj Rathod here you go https://s3.postimg.io/w6qp101mr/image.jpg

Comment: this is the output i want https://s3.postimg.io/qb1crcbpf/image.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this function in your controller.....

```
  public function get_jobsheets() {
      $this->db->select('jobsheets.id, jobsheets.vehicle_number, GROUP_CONCAT(jobsheets_tasks.task) as task');  
      $this->db->from('jobsheets');
      $this->db->join('jobsheets_tasks', 'jobsheets_tasks.jobsheet_id = jobsheets.id');
      $this->db->group_by('jobsheets.id, jobsheets.vehicle_number'); 
      $this->db->order_by('jobsheets.id', 'desc');
      $query = $this->db->get();
      if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
          foreach ($query->result()as $row){
              $data[] = $row;
          }
          return $data ;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Wow this is working & one thing. in the table the tasks now showing next to each other format like task1, task2.

how can i show them one after another

like this i mean

https://s3.postimg.io/qb1crcbpf/image.jpg

Comment: you can try this solution for group_contact with next line etc..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285035/group-concat-mysql-new-line

Answer (score 0):

As my Understanding If your query working fine then check the syntax of foreach loop table... Close the `<tr>` tag

```
<?php 
foreach($result as $jobsheet)  {
 ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->id;?></td>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->vehicle_number;?></td>
          <td><?php echo  $customer->task;?></td></tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes at the moment the query is fine & in my real code the <tr> is closed.