# Creating a Join Query for a one-to-many table relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join, one-to-many

I have a table (Table `D`) that has a field that has another table (Table `M`) associated with it which contains a set of rows that reference a single row in table `D`.

Can (and if so, how) can I create a SQL Query that will not only select the fields from `D`, but join with table `M`, returning all the row values (only from one column) in a single result column, but all concatenated together (preferably with some sort of escaping so it can't be contaminated by rogue data in `M`)?

EDIT:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| DataRowID | DataName | RandomField |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 1         | Foo      | Alice       |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 2         | Bar      | Bob         |
+-----------+----------+-------------+
| 3         | Baz      | Charlie     |
+-----------+----------+-------------+


+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| MetaRowID | DataRowID | MetaValue |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1         | Mercury   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 2         | 1         | Venus     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 3         | 1         | Earth     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 4         | 2         | Mars      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 5         | 2         | Jupiter   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 6         | 3         | Saturn    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 7         | 3         | Uranus    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 8         | 3         | Neptune   |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 9         | 3         | Pluto     |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Which when `Where DataName = 'Bar'` is Queried,

```
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| DataRowID | DataName | RandomField | MetaData     |
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
| 2         | Bar      | Bob         | Mars,Jupiter |
+-----------+----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings

Comment: Which RBDMS?  I'm assuming MySql from your past questions...

Comment: Some example data and output would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MySql's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT d.ID, GROUP_CONCAT(m.Field) AS ConcatFields
FROM d JOIN m ON d.ID = m.dID
GROUP BY d.ID
```

Comment: For the GROUP_CONCAT, how does it glue the values together? also, let's say it just uses `,`s and there is a `,` in the field value, does it get escaped?

Comment: @cgoddard The default separator is a `,`, but you can pass a different separator to the function as well.  It won't change any of the existing data in the field, so you'll need to `REPLACE` any existing `,`s in the field.

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping as an implementation of such a thing, do you agree?