# explode() function using GROUP SEPARATOR

Tags: php, mysql, explode

As per find through [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping) this I have use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
  `topic_response`.`response`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`comment` SEPARATOR 0x1D ) AS `comment`,
  `topic_response`.`add_date`
FROM `topic_response`
WHERE (topic_id = 286)
    AND (`comment` IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY `response`
ORDER BY `add_date` desc
```

Then my output is properly separated but I don't know how to `explode()` it.

```
explode("0x1D", $comment) or     explode("\0x1D", $comment)
```

This does not work.

Comment: why to start with you are using 0x1D as your separator??

Comment: because <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping> answer goto `2nd` answer @medina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use `chr` function for `explode`.Basically `0x1D` is `ascii` string `29`

```
explode(chr(29), $comment)
```

Without no any doubts it solves in all condition.

Answer (score 3):

If you still want to use 0x1D as seprartor, you can use following `explode` syntax:

```php
explode("\x1D", $comment)
```

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping > goto second answer

Comment: Copy my comment why dont you ;)

Comment: No, I wasn't refresh comments before posting :)

Comment: `explode` works perfectly:

`$ php
<?php print_r(explode("\x1D", "One record" . chr(0x1D) . "Two record" . chr(0x1D) . "Three record")); ?>
Array
(
    [0] => One record
    [1] => Two record
    [2] => Three record
)`

Comment: not works beacause if string contains `1D` then goes wrong again

Comment: Please give me your string

Comment: @Maxim it works I have tested properly but i found my answer as perfect way

Comment: @Maxim Let me check all possible scenarios for `explode`

Comment: But why oh why not just select the comments without the group concat. Group concat is more load costly then just looping through the rows. Especially with php having to deal with the explodes. Its just silly yo do it this way ..

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `0x1D` as your seperator?

A way more convenient solution would to be to change `GROUP_CONCAT('comment' SEPARATOR 0x1D )` to `GROUP_CONCAT('comment' SEPARATOR "|" )` and then just do `explode("|", $comment);`.

If you expect `"|"` in your 'comments' you can replace the `"|"` with any string. So `"asd42gfqwasdff33"` would also be a valid seperator, which is quite unlikely to show up as a character in your comments.

But the real question is: why are you group concatting your comments and then exploding the results while you could just loop through the sql results (leaving the group_concat out).

Comment: no `comment` may be contains `|` sign so it gets false values using `explode`

Comment: In that case just use "1927rfqpyfy39" as your seperator :) It can be any string. In any case its simpler then using a binary character. A totally different question however is: why are you group concatting comments and then exploding them again. Woulnt it be better to just loop your sql results ?

Comment: May be `1` in comment then it gives false values using `explode` :)

Comment: Make it whatever string you want, the longer the string. The less chance you can actually encounter it.. But better yet: don't use group concat when you need to itterate through comments ... Just loop the normal select sql results..

Comment: @DevalShah, no, `1` letter in comment don't give false results when your separator is `^12&nbahjkYg1`

Comment: @Maxim  Please <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452357/mysql-group-concat-escaping> answer goto `2nd` answer

Comment: If you are really determined though to stick with your binary explode.. it might help to leave the 0. `explode("\x1D", $comment)` probably works. But I still dont know why you want to use the "left cursor" ascii value as a seperator o.O

Comment: exploding by `1D` should work with `"\x1D"` since `"0x1D"` would be interpreted as a string, to test it do `echo "0x1D";` you'll get `0x1D` as result.